# Unexpected files in newly created flutter package

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-packages

I have created a new flutter package with `flutter create --template=package` but is has created some unexpected files/folders for example

```
test_package 
  --android
    --local.properties
```

This local.properties contain local paths:

```
sdk.dir=/Users/me/Library/Android/sdk
flutter.sdk=/Users/me/fvm/versions/3.7.12 (I am using fvm for flutter version management)
```

I have looked if other packages include this in their gitignore but haven't found one which makes me wonder if I made a mistake with the package creation or should I simply add it to gitignore and don't worry about it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can not see anything wrong.. This is required file for Android. Standalone Android project also contain this file.

Comment: Okay but if this contains a local path to my sdk, I am not supposed to commit this to version control right?

Comment: Yes. you need to add it in gitignore with in Android folder.